# get started with azure mobile service api

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I've create 2 API and my page still look like this

[image]

I expect I can see something like this?

[image]

Comment: @Jonathan create 2 api. I should see at least 2 right?

Comment: Neither of your images work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you posted first shows that your site is running a Node.JS backend, which cannot provide the API explorer screen shown in the second image.

That screen is only available to the .NET backend and will not be visible on the site root - it is on the /help endpoint, protected by the application key so as not to be public.

Comment: Oh I see, but how can I test the first image's api? in azure itself?

Comment: Right - you can always try hitting the APIs using an HTTP client/tool like Fiddler or Postman.